# Utils module not imported

Tags: python, import

I have downloaded [this package of Python Utils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-utils/) , and tried to install it, by entering the folder and typing:

```
python setup.py install
```

The output seems fine: the package installed and all dependencies processed.
However, when I try to import:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Dec 12 2011, 16:10:05) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named utils
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is called `python_utils`, not `utils`. `import python_utils` should work.

Comment: Thanks! Then, could you please tell me what is the `utils` package referred [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/Psych216/blob/master/week1_tutorial.ipynb#Tutorial-#1:-Probability-distributions-and-error-bars)?

Comment: @Py-ser: I don't know. It might be some custom module used by that notebook.

Comment: Ok, it is not specified in that page... thanks again!